# How to set Sumatra as default PDF Viewer in RStudio

Tags: r

I want to use Sumatra for viewing Latex Dokuments I make with R because the default R PDF Viewer opens a Sidebar everytime I recompile.

So far I installed Sumatra and used the following code as described at https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/berryFunctions/html/sumatraInitialize.html

```
sumatraInitialize(
  path = sub("pandoc$", "sumatra", Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")),
  roampath = paste0(Sys.getenv("APPDATA"), "/SumatraPDF"),
  openfolder = TRUE
)
```

R spits out:

```
The following file doesn't exist: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming/SumatraPDF
```

I indeed cant find the Roaming folder and also SumatraPDF is located somewhere else.

What should i do?

Comment: The `AppData` directory is often hidden when looking in windows explorer, you'd need to explicitly force windows to show it, perhaps with _Start >> Run >> `%APPDATA%`_. From there, moving around will be informative for you. On my windows box, Sumatra is installed as `"c:/Users/r2/AppData/Local/SumatraPDF"` (local, not roaming). Perhaps you should be using `%localappdata%` outside of R and `Sys.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")` in your code above.

Comment: What catches my eye immediately is the mix of forward and backwards slash in the error message. Maybe you should try a backwards slash (`"\SumatraPDF"`) to match the windows format?

Comment: @uke, I don't think that's related. On windows, R will happily deal with either forward- or back-slashes, even mixed, so long as they delimit the components of the path correctly. For instance, `"C:\\Users/r2\\AppData/Local\\SumatraPDF"` works just fine. If something is not working because of that, then either it's not in R at all or it's in the `berryFunctions` package, in whatever is being done there.

Answer (score 0):

On my windows system, SumatraPDF installs under `~/AppData/Local/`, not `AppData/Roaming/`. That means you should be able to use:

```r
sumatraInitialize(
  path = sub("pandoc$", "sumatra", Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")),
  roampath = file.path(Sys.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"), "SumatraPDF"),
  openfolder = TRUE
)
```

Comment: No error seen yet, you're likely editing, but ... I know nothing about `sumatraInitialize`, so if it's about that then I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Error: in sumatraInitialize -> openFile -> checkFile: (With current getwd: C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Dokumente)
The following file doesn't exist: C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/sumatra/tools
Additional: Warning:
1: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  file 'C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/sumatra/tools/sumatrapdfrestrict.ini' can not be created. Reason 'No such file or directory'
2: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  file 'C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/sumatra/tools/SumatraPDF-settings.txt' can not be created. Reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: That sounds like a bug report against `berryFunctions`. In the interim, try `dir.create("C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/sumatra/tools/", recursive=TRUE)` and then rerun your code. If it works, file a [new bug report](https://github.com/brry/berryFunctions/issues/new). If it doesn't, you'll likely still need a bug report, though it's not clear to me what the underlying problem is.